# PHP Snippet - WordPress problem on Edge/Firefox

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a strange problem...

I have a PHP snippet that i'm using inside Wordpress and the plugin SNIPPETS.

The code is working is fine in Chrome but for whatever reason, nothing is showing up in Edge or Firefox.

I just want to display a different icon based on a custom user field.

Here is my code

```
 function ajax_13xx()

 { $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

 if ( $current_user->s_managed == Yes  ) { 

  return '<div align="right"><img src="abc.com/onswitch20.jpg"> </div>' ;    

 }

  if ( $current_user->s_managed == No  ) { 

  return '<div align="right"><img src="abc.com/offswitch20.jpg"></div>' ;  

  }
}

add_shortcode('managetoggle', 'ajax_13xx');
```

I'm using Elementor and the Shortcode widget for [managetoggle]

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Regards,
Nathalie

Comment: I didn't know `Yes` was a constant, (well I know its not a default one) but that is how you are using it.    If it's not defined PHP will convert it to a string `Yes` but it will issue a `notice`. Something like `Use of undefined constant assumed 'Yes'`. It may work but it's not really correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `else` block.

```
if ( $current_user->s_managed == 'Yes'  ) { //make this a string not a constant    
  return '<div align="right"><img src="abc.com/onswitch20.jpg"> </div>' ;        
}else{     
  return '<div align="right"><img src="abc.com/offswitch20.jpg"></div>' ;      
}
```

Because this is a boolean value, we can simply use `else`, you want the `No` in else because we could use `0` or `No` or `Null` Generally anything that is `falsy`.  This will also be like a plank time (smallest unit of time possible) faster as only one condition needs to be checked.

Another even better way to write this is like this:

```
function ajax_13xx()
     return '<div align="right"><img src="abc.com/'.(wp_get_current_user()->s_managed == 'Yes' ?  'on' : 'off').'switch20.jpg"> </div>' ;  
}
```

Then you keep your code a bit more DRY (don't repeat yourself)

Answer (score 0):

Found solution already...

Added this line...

```
if ( NULL == $current_user->s_managed ) {
```

Comment: You could have fixed it with `if(!defined('No')) define('No', null)` and `if(!defined('Yes')) define('Yes', 'Yes')`  As your conditions use constants and not strings.  see my comment on the question itself.